# How to solve 429 Too many Requests

Tags: java, spring, firebase, redis, resttemplate

My spring application uses a `RedisList` to get and send some notifications via `restTemplate`.
In addition, I'm using a firebase function to do this.
The problem is that when i try to send more than 50 notifications in a min I obtain this error:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$TooManyRequests:
>   429 Too Many Requests     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:97)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:123)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:586)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   it.visualsoftware.notificator.RestTemplate.RestTemplateService.SendNotification(RestTemplateService.java:46)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   it.visualsoftware.notificator.redis.RedisQueueSend.listener(RedisQueueSend.java:54)
>   ~[classes/:na]

Is there a way to increase this limitation? does is it related to `Firebase` or `restTemplate`?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I solved! The problem was related to Firebase, I didn't set a billing account and with the Firebase basic plan (spark) you are only allowed to invoke 50 functions every 100s.